# Single Sign On Html Page with Restful Service

Tags: javascript, html, active-directory, windows-authentication, restful-authentication

Let me explain what's my plan.

Actually I write a website in HTML5 with Javascript.
This website do an ajax call to a c# RESTful service.
Both, the website and the service, are located on a windows server 2012 at the iis 8.

The website is located in an virtual directory of the default web site.
The service is added as an application to the server.

The server is running inside our intranet including AD.

I access the website by the url: http://example/Auth.

My goal is that the user didn't have to login manually, because it's already done at windows login.

This should be done by using windows authentication i guess, but when i activate it, i'm prompted to enter my credentials.
After entering them everything works fine. If they were correct i can use the website, otherwise i get 401 as expected.

First question: what do i have to do, to be logged in automatically if i'm a valid user of the AD?

Wheter logged in automatically or manually i'm not able to get the username of the logged in user and pass it to the service.

Second question: how to get the username and pass it to the server?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was finally quite simple to solve my problem.
All i had to do, was to add the domain to the url and get a full qualified url like: example.mydomain.com/Auth.
If i try toaccess this site now, there is no prompt shown and even the credentials get passed to auth following services etc.